# Tkinter pack is not applying bg, width or height, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm new to tkinter and I'm following a tutorial, the app pops up and everything but the height, width and background aren't working, idk what I'm doing wrong.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
from tkinter import *
import os

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700,width=700,bg='red')
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tested your code and it worked correctly with a red 700x700 background. Share more info e.g. environment, full code, etc.

Comment: This isn't the issue, but just as a heads-up: you don' t need `from tkinter import *` if you've already done `import tkinter as tk`. You can also remove `from tkinter import filedialog, Text` and just use `tk.filedialog` and `tk.Text` instead where needed. And FIWIW, I also can't reproduce this issue (on Windows). What OS are you running?

Comment: Post a [mre] with debugging details.